# invoke scrapy spider with rest api

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, tornado

need help

i made a spider that the only thing is to yield url and descriptions from search-engine site

my spider code is:

```
def __init__(self, keyword, se = 'bing', pages = 50,  *args, **kwargs):
    super(KeywordSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.keyword = keyword.lower()
    self.searchEngine = se.lower()
    self.selector = SearchEngineResultSelectorsURL[self.searchEngine]
    self.image_selector = SearchEngineResultSelectorsIMAGES[self.searchEngine]
    pageUrls = searResultPages(keyword, se, int(pages))
    for url in pageUrls:
        print(url)
        self.start_urls.append(url)

def parse(self, response):
    images_dict = dict()
    images_dict['images'] = []
    for url in Selector(response).xpath(self.selector):


        yield {'url':''.join(url.xpath('h2/a/@href').extract()).strip(),
               'title':''.join(url.xpath('h2/a//text()').extract()).strip(),


               }
```

what i need to do is now for this :

1. invoking this spider with A REST interface that accepts a keyword and search engine
2. return response in json

example:
i need to run a server - open rest api - do:

```
localhost:5000/search?keyword={0}&search_engine={1}
```

The server will need to call the spider and crawl with him
when getting results- he needs to send them back to server on a json format

what i made is:

```
class Search(resource.Resource):
isLeaf = True
def render_GET(self, request):
    args = request.args

    added_images_url=False
    count_results =0
    # here we want to get the value of user (i.e. ?user=some-value)
    if b'keyword' not in  args:
        request.setResponseCode(400)
        return bytes('no keyword param','utf-8')
    if b'search_engine' not in  args:
        request.setResponseCode(400)
        return bytes('no search_engine param','utf-8')
    if b'num_of_results' not in  args:
        request.setResponseCode(400)
        return bytes('no num_of_results param','utf-8')

    keyword,search_engine,num_of_results = self.decode_values_from_dict(args)
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'FEED_FORMAT':'json',
        'FEED_URI':'search_results.json',
        'ITEM_PIPELINES':{'BingCrawler.main.MyPipeline': 1}
        })
    if os.path.isfile(FILE_NAME):
        os.remove(FILE_NAME)



    process.crawl(KeywordSpider,keyword=keyword,se = search_engine,\
                  pages=(int(math.ceil(int(num_of_results)/NUMBER_OF_RESULTS_PER_SEARCH_ENGINE[search_engine.upper()]))))


    process.start()
    json_file = open(FILE_NAME,'r').read()
    json_obj_items = json.loads(json_file)
    result_items = [item for item in json_obj_items if 'images_url' not in item]
    image_item = [item for item in json_obj_items if 'images_url' in item]
    result_item_requested_amount = result_items[0:int(num_of_results)]
    result_item_requested_amount.extend(image_item)   
    return json.dumps(result_item_requested_amount)




def decode_values_from_dict(self,args):
    return args[b'keyword'][0].decode('utf-8'),args[b'search_engine'][0].decode('utf-8'),args[b'num_of_results'][0].decode('utf-8')
```

and

```
root = Search()
factory = server.Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
reactor.run()
```

But i get reactorAlreadyRunning exception

I need to use non-blocking - asynchronius api 
Tried to work with twisted, didnt succeedd

Please help... Thank you! (:

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to help you write your first post. As it is now, your question is too broad - you need to come with a more specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CrawlerRunner` instead of `CrawlerProcess` if you're going to use the spider within a Twisted app. That should solve your `reactorAlreadyRunning` issue.